# Is there a program that automatically styles C files?

Tags: c, coding-style, indentation, pretty-print

I think the title is self-explanatory. Would be handy for large files with lots of style violations. Thanks guys :)

Comment: When you say style, do you mean coding pattern style ("coding standard") or just textual formatting?

Comment: Just textual formatting - correcting things like indentation, spaces, naming conventions. Thanks for all the feedback guys, I have just tried out Indent and it seems to be what I was after. Sorry I can't vote anyone's answer up for being helpful, apparently I don't have enough reputation yet :P cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) is the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sf.net). It formats C, C++, C# and Java and is written in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an IDE which can style source files, [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliossr2) is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Visual SlickEdit has some good code formatting tools built-in and a powerful scripting system if you want to customize it further.